# GMail imap_fetchbody does not work

Tags: php, gmail

I'm trying to read an email body from gmail with `imap_fetchbody` and PHP, but it does not work, it does not print the body.

The mail has attachments and its Mime-type is `text/html`.
This is my code (with other kind of email, it works):

```
$string = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($con,$email,2));
```

This is my PHP code:

```
$con is imap_open($server, $login, $password); 
$email are email from imap_search all code is;
$connessione = imap_open($server, $login, $password); 
$emails = imap_search($connessione, 'UNSEEN FROM "cc@cc.com"'); 
if (!empty($emails)) 
{ 
  foreach ($emails as $email) 
  { 
    $string = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($connessione,$email,2)); 
  } 
}
```

$string is this:
 ----boundary_13267_d232a838-e6ee-4fb8-bc76-85484f4b0772 Content-Type: text/html Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Cgo8aHRtbD4KPGhlYWQ+CjxNRVRBIGh....

Can someone help me?

Comment: This doesn't give enough details to what you are trying to do here.
Show how you are getting the $con and $email variables. Also have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033507/how-to-fetch-the-gmail-message-body-with-php-and-imap

Comment: Do not add comments, edit your question. You cannot format code in comments, not all comments may be shown initially or in the correct order. Please edit your question and include a [mcve].

Comment: I included your comment's contents into the question (and did some other fixes).

Comment: i'm sorry, thank you